# Restricting access to certain out of the box SharePoint web services

Tags: web-services, permissions

As the title explains, I want to restrict access for certain web services in the SharePoint environment.  Is this possible and how do you pull it off?  Not finding much to support that it is.  I do not wish to disable all of the services, only a select few.  If I could do so on a permissions basis that would be even better (i.e. disable a select few for all except collection administrators).

Thanks!

Reference to the services I refer to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862916(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: this is for SP2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but what if you used location web.config permissions for the different web services you need to change the permissions on ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871 )?

I think the web.config you would need to change is located here:  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI

I'm also not sure if this is a supported scenerio or not.  I know you are not allowed to modify ootb files and receive support, but web.config files are meant to be easily modified.

Comment: You could probably at least deploy a feature and use [SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.aspx)

Comment: Eventhough there is a web.config in the ISAPI folder it should be sufficient to set the location in the zones IIS folder as web.config settings are inherited from the web.config in Framework/Config folder down to the local web.config.

Answer (score 2):

For SP2007:

Central Admin-> Application management -> Application Security -> User permissions for Web Application.

If you un-check the following:
"Use Remote Interfaces  -  Use SOAP, Web DAV, or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site."

It will prevent anyone from using any of the web services,  SOAP, WebDav, SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I think this would be acceptable if I was willing to disable ALL of the services, which I do not wish to do.  I should have clarified in the question.  I will edit now.